# Swap_Usage is high in the Linux system increases. How to reduce it

Tags: swap, virtual-memory

@ mr.spuratic,

Can you please explain how to reduce swap_usage memory in the system considering active and inactive memory.

Will the command `free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && echo "" && free` helps in reducing the swap usage?

Thanks
JS

Comment: Why do you want to "reduce swap usage", what do you [think](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) you'll achieve with that? The only sensible thing to do for reducing swap usage is to either buy more memory or start fewer programs.

Comment: Who is mr.spuratic?

Comment: Maybe this guy? - https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/31352/mr-spuratic

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat recommand to avoid 0. Choose 10 or 5 in value not least for swapiness.

Extract of tuning docs RHEL7 :
**Warning
Setting 
swappiness==0
 will very aggressively avoids swapping out, which
increase the risk of OOM killing under strong memory and I/O pressure. ***